# IPhone app to block callers at specific times?

Tags: ios, applications, iphone

Is there an app or any other way on an iPhone 5 to block a given caller at specified times?

Specifically, work keeps calling at all times of the day, every day. Is there a way to send their calls (and not everyone else's) to voicemail on evenings and weekends, but ring normally during working hours?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/call-bliss-silence-calls-text/id575698521?mt=8# may partially solve your problem (I haven't tried it myself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do Not Disturb can do that, no 3rd party app needed.

You might have to juggle a new contacts group, because it only allows to receive calls from one group at a time, or favourites - so to exclude 'work' you might need to create a new group containing 'everyone else'

[image]

You can also toggle it manually from the Lock Screen

[image]

Comment: I think this might be the easiest way. The trade-off is that WhatsApp notifications etc would be silenced too but it looks like there's no way around that. Thanks!

Comment: With the above suggestion you also won't get calls from non-contacts. Best is to set explicit healthy boundaries with your work.

Comment: @Jean-PierreParent - Yup. The only people who can call me outside 'sensible' hours are my family. Boundaries are good. Everybody else can just wait til the morning.