# App to stop ex calling outside of court ordered hour

Tags: call, do-not-disturb

I have an abusive ex and we have a contact order for the children which allows him to call between 6.30-7.30 each day. However he continues to call all hours of the day and night. Is there an app to stop him calling outside of that hour? I’ve tried DND and bed time but doesn’t seem to work

Comment: Record **all** the calls as evidence to send back to court.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197278/iphone-app-to-block-callers-at-specific-times#197300